# Find location on screen of a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, image, awtrobot

I am trying to find the location on the screen a certain image is, but I'm quite new to Java so I think I could be messing this up.. here's what I've tried:

```
public Point getLocationOfImage(int[][] pixels){
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Robot robot;
    Point point = new Point(0, 0);;
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        robot = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Dimension screenDimensions = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    retry:
    for(int i = 0; i < screenDimensions.width; i++){
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < screenDimensions.height; i2++){
            //check region
            for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++){
                for(int j2 = 0; j2 < 30; j2++){
                    BufferedImage test = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(i + j, i2 + j2, 30, 30));
                    toDrawG.drawImage(test, 30, 0, null);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(test.getRGB(i + j, i2 + j2) == pixels[j][j2]){
                        continue;}
                    else{
                        break retry;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return point;
    }
```

So anyway that doesn't seem to work at all, and the pixels[][] is from another function:

```
public static int[][] getPixels(BufferedImage i){
    int temp[][] = new int[i.getWidth()][i.getHeight()];
    for(int n = 0; n < i.getWidth(); n++){
        for(int n2 = 0; n2 < i.getHeight(); n2++){
            temp[n][n2] = i.getRGB(n, n2);
        }   
    }
    return temp;
}
```

but as far as I'm concerned, that function works fine.. Is there something I'm missing? I'm sure someone on here could spot my error in a matter of minutes..

Comment: *"Is there something I'm missing"*  Do you mean besides a question mark & an SSCCE?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
(And please don't forget to add a question mark to questions.)

Comment: Does the image have solid color, does it include transparency or partial transparency?  Can you upload a (small in bytes) test image to use?

Comment: The Image is a 30x30 image of the screen, I'm sure that information should suffice, By the way.. how do I upload images to this?

Comment: So, you have a 30x30 screen-grab, and you want to figure out which part of the screen it came from?  What software grabs the 30x30 image? *"how do I upload images to this?"*  If you have enough rep. there should be a button above the message posting/editing form.  If not, upload it to ..image shack or whatever, & provide an URL.

Comment: No software grabs the 30x30 image:
                        BufferedImage test = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(i + j, i2 + j2, 30, 30));
is the screen grab. And thanks, i didn't think of that.

Comment: *"am trying to find the location on the screen a certain image"* from comment `BufferedImage test = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(i + j, i2 + j2, 30, 30));` Umm.. that location would seem to be contained in `i + j`,`i2 + j2`.  Or in other words, I have less idea what you are trying to achieve at this moment, than I (thought I did) when I first read the question!

Comment: This graphic might help?
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34854809/example.png